# ios swift popup custom view irrespective of current view controller every 30 minutes

Tags: ios, swift, popup

i need to have a custom view controller to popup independent of currently presenting view controller, 
it should show every 30 seconds, and when user clicks on popup, it should hide or dismiss.

i have been searching but nothing worked , Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: modal or non modal?  non modal you at a view to uiscreen.mainscreen.  modal present vc from rootviewcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

Write logic in AppDelegate. It is a singleton class and instance of it stays in memory for the entire life cycle of App and you can present view controller using

```
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(yourVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

You need not know which view controller is on top currently :)

Comment: @Khushboo : Use this code inside of a timer method.

Comment: @Poles : Thanks buddy :) Yup u are 100 % correct :)

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me try this and let me know:

```
let imageV: UIImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(90, 0, 80, 80))
                imageV.image = UIImage(named: "stop_record")!
                self.message = UIAlertView(title: “Custom view”, message: “Processing…”, delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle:nil)
                let v: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(10, 20, 100, 100))
                let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action:#selector(SONGS.new(_:)))
                tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
                if   tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired == 1
                {
                    imageV.userInteractionEnabled = true
                    imageV.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
                    v.addSubview(imageV)
                    self.timer.invalidate()
                }
                self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(180.0, target: self, selector: #selector(SONGS.displayAlert), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
                let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(90, 40, 100, 101))
                label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
                self.message.setValue(v, forKey: "accessoryView")
                self.message.tag = 3
                self.message.show()




func displayAlert
{
    self.message.dismissWithClickedButtonIndex(0,animated: true)

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For showing pop up after every 30 seconds, you should use NSTimer with interval of 30 seconds. After every 30 secs a selector(say showPopUp) method is called which you specify while initialising NSTimer. In this showPopUp you should show popup you can use UIAlertController and add that on window.

All the above implementation should be done in Appdelegate.m